# why I am getting the wrong output?

Tags: python

```
item = "burrito"
meat = "chicken"
queso = False
guacamole = False
double_meat = False
if item == "quesadilla":
    base_price = 4.0
elif item == "burrito":
    base_price = 5.0
else:
    base_price = 4.5


if meat == "steak" or "pork":
    if double_meat:  
        if guacamole and queso and not item == "nachos":
            base_price += 1.00 + 1.50 + 0.50 + 1.00
        elif guacamole:
            base_price += 0.50 + 1.50 + 1.00
        else:
            base_price += 0.50 + 1.50 
    else:
        if guacamole and queso and not item == "nachos":
            base_price += 1.00 + 0.50 + 1.00
        elif guacamole:
            base_price += 0.50 + 1.00
        else:
            base_price += 0.50  
else:
    if double_meat:  
        if guacamole and queso and not item == "nachos":
            base_price += 1.00 + 1.00 + 1.00
        elif guacamole:
            base_price += 1.00 + 1.00
        else:
            base_price += 1.00 
    else:
        if guacamole and queso and not item == "nachos":
            base_price += 1.00 + 1.00
        elif guacamole:
            base_price += 1.00
        else:
            base_price += 0.00
print(base_price)
```

The code should calculate the cost of the meal under given conditions ( line 1 to 5 ). These conditions can change. The output of the above code should be `5.0` but I am getting an output equals to `5.5`.
The scenario is the last `else` statement of the code where `base_price` should be  `5+0.00 = 5.00` as the price of burrito is `5.0`. So, how I am getting `5.5`?

Comment: _Why_ should you get "5.0"? If we don't know what the code should do, and you have a math error, it's impossible for us to answer

Comment: The code should calculate the cost of the meal under given conditon( line 1 to 5 )

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value

Comment: @roganjosh well I am not allowed to use lists or set. I must execute this program completely with if..elif...else statement

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
if meat == "steak" or "pork":
```

with

```
if meat == "steak" or meat == "pork":
```

Explanation:

`meat == "steak" or "pork"` will be executed sequentially (`==` has higher priority than `or`), so `meat=="steak"` is False, and the expression will be `False or "Pork"` which is `"pork"` which is True.

```
>>> meat = 'chicken'
>>> meat == 'steak' or 'pork'
'pork'
>>> meat == 'steak' or meat == 'pork'
False
```

Comment: You edited your explanation out :P Why does `meat == 'steak' or 'pork'` print `pork`?

Comment: This is a bit of a rabbit hole of an answer, because the first question I would ask is why I get a bool for one condition and a string for another. It's best to close such questions as dupes unless you have a comprehensive answer

Comment: @roganjosh more than happy to do that, not enough reputation though

Comment: It's probably just personal preference, but I find `if meat in ('steak', 'pork')` more concise and readable.